Issues with "sequences of non-printing characters" in Readline's variables on the Bash prompt
Im trying to customize my prompt as well as with the editing mode at the prompt. But i'm having some troubles with the non-printing characters in the variable vi-cmd-mode-string and vi-ins-mode-string.

~/.inputrc:
set show-all-if-ambiguous on
set completion-ignore-case on
set print-completions-horizontally on
set horizontal-scroll-mode on
set colored-stats on
# vi style keystrokes
set editing-mode vi
set show-mode-in-prompt on
set vi-cmd-mode-string \1\e[42;30m\2cmd\1\e[0m\2
set vi-ins-mode-string \1\e[43;30m\2ins\1\e[0m\2

"\C-n": menu-complete
"\C-p": menu-complete-backward
TAB: menu-complete


When i enter Bash it starts in insert mode, when i press Escape the place of the mode it just prints some of the characters literaly from the variables. They are enclosed between \1 and \2 so what did do wrong? What did i misinterpret from the manual? Here is an demonstration of the issue:

This just happens when I use the \1non-printable_sequence\2. I've already enclosed all the string in quotes (") and nothing.

Bash version: 5.2
Terminal emulators: Tilix v1.9.4 and Windows Terminal v1.20.11781.0
Both showed the same thing. Don't think they have something to do with it.
OS: Ubuntu 22.04

P.S.: resizing the emulator window it works again.

This also happens for me on Mac OS 14.5 with Bash 5.2. I can't find anything in the bash manual explaining it, so this is an interesting bug.
